# Google App Engine adding functionality to webapp2.RequestHandler

Tags: python, google-app-engine, inheritance

My GAE app runs into CORS problems with POST requests. I found that the simple solution is to call `self.response.headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")` in my request handlers. I would like to not have to call this for every POST handler I write, so I created a mediary class called `PostHandler` that inherits from `webapp2.RequestHandler` and that my handlers that deal with POST request will inherit from. This is how I implemented this class:

```
class PostHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def __init__(self, request, response):
        super(PostHandler, self).__init__(request, response)
        self.response.headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
```

Will this do what I expect it to do? If I have another handler:

```
class Login(PostHandler):
    def post(self):
        #blah
```

Will that handler be a proper `webapp2.RequestHandler`? Or do I have to do something different?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am doing the same thing in this way and its working fine

```
class PostHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def dispatch(self):
        self.response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
        super(PostHandler, self).dispatch()

class Login(PostHandler):
    def post(self):
```

Comment: do you mean `super(PostHandler, self).dispatch()`?